# Connecting and Executing mongodb commands remotely through pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Below is my python code which connects remotely to mongodb host and executes mongodb command "db.serverStatus().connections".

Expected output from below script is :

```
{ 
"current" : 43,
"available" : 51157,
"totalCreated" : NumberLong(3988)
}
```

But I'm not getting any output.....

PYTHON CODE:

```
import pymongo

host = 'mongo_server.com'
port = 27018
db_name='test'
user='user'
passwrd='password'

def get_connection():
    con=pymongo.Connection(host,port)
    db=con[db_name]
    try:
        db.authenticate(user,passwrd)
        print db.command("serverStatus")["connections"]

    except:
        return None
    return db

get_connection()
```

Comment: Try to connect using mongo shell from same box as you executed above from ... Post errors if any ... ping mongo server host to confirm visibility

Comment: Try running your python directly on mongo server if possible to confirm code is OK

Answer (score 0):

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

**mongodb://** is a required prefix to identify that this is a string in the standard connection format.

**username:password@** are optional. If given, the driver will attempt to login to a database after connecting to a database server. For some authentication mechanisms, only the username is specified and the password is not, in which case the ":" after the username is left off as well
host1 is the only required part of the URI. It identifies a server address to connect to.

**:portX** is optional and defaults to :27017 if not provided.

**/database** is the name of the database to login to and thus is only relevant if the username:password@ syntax is used. If not specified the "admin" database will be used by default.

**?options** are connection options. Note that if database is absent there is still a / required between the last host and the ? introducing the options. Options are name=value pairs and the pairs are separated by "&". For backwards compatibility, ";" is accepted as a separator in addition to "&", but should be considered as deprecated.

[click here for detailed explanation on above command](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html)